# Change link href attribute on the fly with text input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I've got an input and a link. I need to change the link's href on the fly *a.k.a* when user types and it would be super great if there's a way to also detect if user pastes something in there.

Any idea how to achieve this via jQuery?

```
<input type="text" id="my-input">
<a id="my-link" target="_blank" href="www.something.com/<!--input text here-->/something/">
Click me!
</a>
```

---

What I've digged up:

```
//Somehow get the the input value if it has changed

//Change the href attribute
$("#my-link").attr("href", "//www.something.com/" + textFromInput +"/something/");
```

Comment: Put your code in the `change` event of the input.

Comment: Could you copy-paste my code and add your suggestion as an answer so that I could see how it would look like? Thanks.

Comment: Binding event handlers is one of the most basic jQuery operations. Please show what you've tried, then I can help you understand what you did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `keyup` event to handle typing on-the-fly

```
$('#my-input').keyup(
    function(){     
        var textFromInput = $("#my-input").val();
        $("#my-link").attr("href", "https://www.google.com?q=" + textFromInput); 
});
```

[Check out this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdryd3ep/)

---

You can also use `change` one, but it will fire when the input field's focus is lost - it will be ok too since you have to click on link to get effect (meaning you will have lost focus on input)

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Do you have any quick tips how to make it work on dynamically loaded content like if it was inside Bootstrap tooltip for example?

Comment: The problem with dynamically loaded content is that you cannot bind an event before it is loaded - there is nothing to bind obviously - in old jQuery version there were [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) method superseded by [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) that can handle situation like this

Comment: `$('#my-input').on( 'keyup', function() { rest is the same` didn't do the trick for some reason, I guess I have to dig into tooltip docs to find the right event or something.